# Portable binaries and the libexec path

Tags: libraries, portability

I want to build portable binaries for [apache mesos](http://mesos.apache.org). One of the problems is that it uses some binaries located in the `libexec` folder during execution.

When compiling, I set `--prefix` to `/tmp/test`. The built binaries are then copied and bundled up into an archive for distribution.

The problem is that when running the binaries after deployment, it searches in `/tmp/test/mesos/libexec/mesos/mesos-fetcher` instead of `/opt/deploy/mesos/libexec/mesos/mesos-fetcher`.

I tried adding `/opt/deploy/mesos/libexec/mesos/mesos-fetcher` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Is there anyway to set the search path for `libexec` using an environment varible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be some general environment variable I can set.

In the case of mesos, I needed to pass in `--launcher_dir=/opt/deploy/mesos/libexec/mesos/` when launching the slave. Alternatively, the environment variable `MESOS_LAUNCHER_DIR` can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting

`--libexecdir=DIR` during configuration? According to --options, this should set program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]

Comment: Yes, however if I set that to `--libexecdir=/some/dir`, it will still search in `/some/dir`. I needed a way where the binaries should still work even if not installed in `/some/dir`. Setting the `MESOS_LAUNCHER_DIR` environment variable during deployment solves this.