# Should libexec folders be added to some PATH-like variables?

Tags: filesystems, path, executable

#### Situation

Some programs that I build from source have a directory `libexec` in the installation directory (for example, gnuplot). As a matter of rule, I add a

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${installation directory}lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

to my `.bashrc` when I have `lib` folders. Likewise with `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` if `${insdir}/bin` and `${insdir}/lib/pkgconfig` exist. I have developed this practice based on the many indications to do so gathered with usage.

I can see that the files contained in `libexec` are binary executables.

#### Questions

What is their purpose in contrast to the executables stowed in `bin`?

Should dedicated variables (in the guise of `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`) be set to make them known to the shell environment? If not, would `PATH` would do just as fine? Or perhaps there's no need ever to set anything because they are used by special programs that are content with a relative path?

This topic is close to [Portable binaries and the libexec path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227942/portable-binaries-and-the-libexec-path) which addresses a similar point when creating libexec files in a package, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libexec` is intended for private binaries, *i.e.* binaries which are used by a program but which shouldn't be available generally. See the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s07.html):

> `/usr/libexec` includes internal binaries that are not intended to be executed directly by users or shell scripts.

So no, you shouldn't add it to any `PATH`-style variables.

Comment: The exception would be cases like homebrew on Macs, which, for packages like coreutils that mask system utilities, keep `ls`, etc. in `.../libexec/gnubin` and uses `gls`, etc. in `/usr/local/bin`. If you want ls to be GNU ls, then it's easiest to add that folder to PATH.

Comment: @StephenKitt Does this hold also when we are outside `/usr`?

Comment: I would say it still holds, yes, regardless of the prefix, except for very specific cases like muru's example.

Comment: Basically programs which need to use binaries that they install in `libexec` are supposed to know where they are.